# Android - ImageButton in RelativeLayout not matching parent size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Fairly new to Android dev, I'm having trouble with a RelativeLayout. In the following XML example, I would expect my ImageButton (on the right, with the '+') to match the RelativeLayout height. However, it doesn't, as shown on this image:
[image: Example]
Why isn't the right button with the '+' matching the maximum possible height ?

Here's the related code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_24dp">
</ImageView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/artist_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_playlist_button_background">
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_of_albums"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_below="@id/artist_name">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for any help or idea.

EDIT: What I want is the right button to occupy the height of the line, i.e. have the same height than the two text zones of the middle plus top and bottom margins, no more no less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can understand from the XML, it seems you want to make the "+" button more clickable.
I would suggest you to have some padding and that should do the job.

EDIT 1 : You may do the following without padding, by aligning Top and Bottom of the ImageView to the relevant TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_24dp">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_of_albums"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_below="@id/artist_name">
</TextView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/artist_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/artist_name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/number_of_albums"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_playlist_button_background">
</ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're right it works, but it's kind of a workaround. What I'm trying to have is the '+' button to occupy the whole line in height no matter its size. This trick won't work if a user changes the text size, and therefore the line size.

Comment: If you are actually trying to make the '+' button occupy the entire height. You can make android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: That's what I've done in the ImageButton. My question is "why it's not working ?"

Comment: Answering to this WHY is a bit difficult, As you have made the RelativeLayout's height depend on it's children's height and then you are specifying to one of it's child to have height of the parent...this is ambiguous, we may not able to justify the working on different Android versions and phone...sometimes this makes a single row fill the entire phone's screen

Comment: I see your point, maybe I'm doing it wrong. What I'm trying to have is in each cell of a list, from left to right, 1 picture, 2 text views in vertical and 1 clickable picture

Comment: You first need to finalize the view which will define the RelativeLayout's height. Let's for say, take the 2 textviews in vertical (may be enclosed in a LinearLayout), then you can make the top and bottom of the clickable picture align with the top and bottom of the 2 textviews so it in-directly gets the height of the parent

Comment: That's what I've just tried, and it works indeed ! I put the 3 first elements (left picture and 2 textViews) in a second RelativeLayout, and aligned the right button top and bottom, and I've got the expected layout ! Thanks a lot. Side question: you talked about a LinearLayout, is it a better solution than 2 enclosed RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Not a better solution to include LinearLayout...but would be easier to manage. We should try to have less hierarchy in the design, but in your scenario it really doesn't matter

Comment: That won't work as there are margins on the TextViews, so there will be the same margins for the ImageButton, and I don't want any. You have to enclose the TextViews in another Layout, and align the ImageButton with this layout

Comment: anyway, you got what you needed..that's more important...good day

Comment: Just in case someone else need it, I have changed the margin to padding

Answer (score 1):

Put your relative layout inside a linear layout that should do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLaout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_background">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_24dp">
</ImageView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/artist_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/artist_cell_playlist_button_background">
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_of_albums"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_button"
    android:layout_below="@id/artist_name">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the result is the same. Why is it supposed to change the result ? As the parent of the ImageButton is still the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Your image may be small. Use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in the `ImageButton`.

Also try removing default padding and margin from the ImageButton by setting them to 0dp.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, same result. The image is indeed quite small, but as I don't ask it to wrap the image, what does the size of the image matter ?

Comment: Try setting the margin and padding to 0dp

Comment: I guess it's not a padding nor margin problem, as when I hardcode the height of the ImageButton (for example 100dp), it occupies the whole line (with no margin).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @rex, I figured out how to do this: enclose the left picture and the 2 TextViews in a RelativeLayout (this sets the size of the main RelativeLayout), and align top and bottom the ImageButton to this layout.
The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/artist_cell"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cell_background">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/artist_plus_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/artist_infos"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/artist_infos"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/plus_button_background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/artistPlusButtonCD">
</ImageButton>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/artist_infos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/artist_plus_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/artist_plus_button">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/album_cover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_music_note_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/albumCoverContentDescription">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/album_cover"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/album_cover">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_of_albums"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/album_cover"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/album_cover"
        android:layout_below="@id/artist_name">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```